# excel hide rows with error values based on dropdown change

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to hide rows in column B9-B40 when Index/Match formula returns "N/A" , now I managed to get it done in VBA when the table is static but I have a dynamic table based on drop-down selection which means the number of N/As returned can be different for each time drop-down selection changes.

Here is what I have right now which hides the rows with N/A based on current drop-down selection, my dropdowns are in C2,C3 and C4. But it doesn't takes any further change in the dropdown into consideration afterwards. I am not very competent with the VBA so any help would be great.

Thanks.

```
Option Explicit


Sub hide_if_error()

    Dim MyCell As Range, Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range("B9:B40")

    For Each MyCell In Rng

        If IsError(MyCell) Then

            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End If

    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just trying to hide any rows with errors in range B9:B40?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to hide all the rows with errors in the B9:B40, errors are coming right at the end of the list, they are never in the middle.

Comment: Would conditional formatting, or a `IFERROR(myformula, "")` cell formula to hide the N/As be good enough? No need for VBA then.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but the problem is I am plotting row values(which is the data labels) in the radar graph and the only way I found hide N/As is when I hide the rows.

Comment: There is another way. Try searching dynamic named ranges for charts.

Comment: tried that  too strangely didn't work either, think this is the final way to do it

Comment: With the `COUNT()` function in the named range instead of the `COUNTA()` function? The later will count the errors.

Comment: In the Define name I used the below formula, which graph recognizes but doesn't ignore N/A's when piloting from the range. when I change COUNTA() to COUNT() in this formula it gives error when I enter it in the pilot data selection section.  

=OFFSET(Sheet4!$B$9;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet4!$B$9:$B$40);1)

Comment: Unfortunately it is a bit fiddly to set up, but I assure you it does work and negates the need for VBA. You might be trying to input the named range into the 'Chart data range' rather than editing the individual series and inputting the named range there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Range("B9:B40").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

You will need a test in advance that errors are present though.

That might look like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub hide_if_error()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")

        .Range("B9:B40").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        If Evaluate("=SUM(IF(ISERROR(" & .Range("B9:B40").Address & "),1))") > 0 Then '<==check if any errors present

            .Range("B9:B40").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If necessary, you could link the above to a worksheet change or dropdown change event so it is fired each time there is an update using the dropdown(s)

For example:

If you data validation was in `C2:C4` you would put in the code pane for the sheet the following event code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ErrHand
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C4")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        hide_if_error
    End If
ErrHand:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note:

The worksheet event code goes in the code pane associate with sheet 4:

[image: Code pane]

The other code goes in a standard module (module 1 here):

[image: Module 1]

Example run:

[image: Test run]

Comment: So I changed the sheet name to Sheet 4 is that the only thing I need to do? with this code I am getting run time error, "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Something like the edit above if the actual sheet is called Sheet4

Comment: Ok now it works but as same as what I had originally, only hides in the first place, without considering change in the dropdown selection.

Comment: What kind of drop down are you using? See my comment at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Oh just saw it, sorry yes it is a data validation drop-down. So you mean I cannot trigger action from that?

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly, you are genius, the only thing not the matter of the original question and I just noticed is when the row is hidden it also hides my graph when it is located next to the table.